# UICollectionViewCell overlapping

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a horizontally scrollable UICollectionView, I am setting the horizontal direction using UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

When I delete one of the cell using -

```
[self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:selectedItemsIndexPaths];
```

I notice that on scrolling back to the first UICollectionViewCell(Which is not visible when the above cell is deleted) overlaps with the second UICollectionViewCell as shown below

[image]

Sometimes instead of overlapping it ends up like -

[image]

My cellForItemAtIndexPath looks like -

```
ABCollectionViewCell *cell = (ABCollectionViewCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"abCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.name.text = [self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.contactButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    cell.clipsToBounds = YES;

    return cell;
```

I have tried all the similar issues solution online but none of them seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated.

UICollectionViewFlowLayout -

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(102.0, 102.0);
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 6.0f;
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 2.0f;
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
      insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform delete like this

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:selectedItemsIndexPaths]; 
} completion:^{
    [self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Comment: How do you determine the size of an item?

Comment: - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  gives the size since the cell size is dynamic

Comment: try [self.collectionView reloadData]; in the completion block.

Comment: still not working. Also it happens only for the first cell and only if the first cell is not visible. if the first cell is visible then this doesn't happen.